# Is it possible to just specify an Azure automation job once, without affecting the schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I would like to specify an Azure Automation Job once ie "Scale DB1 to Standard S2 using credential - mycredential". Currently I have to provide these parameter values every time I set up a new schedule. There seems to be no concept of creating a specific job and a specific schedule and then linking the 2. Yes you do link jobs to schedules, but a schedule can only take one job, so you have to unlink the schedule first before being able to link it to another job.

I guess the desired relationship is:

```
Job -< JobSchedule>- Schedule
```

and we have

```
job -< Schedule.
```

But the job can only be defined when setting up a schedule.

I would like a Job list like:

```
jb-WeekDayNightScaleDownQAV11
jb-WeekDayNightScaleDownQAV12
jb-WeekDayMorningScaleUpQAV11
jb-WeekDayMorningScaleUpQAV12
jb-WeekendStartScaleDownQAV11
jb-WeekendStartScaleDownQAV12
```

For Schedules I would want:

```
sch-WeekdayMorning
sch-WeekdayNight
sch-WeekendStart
```

Having defined these 9 objects, I would like to edit them individually without affecting any of the others. Some linkages might look like:

```
sch-WeekdayMorning
  -jb-WeekDayNightScaleDownQAV11
  -jb-WeekDayNightScaleDownQAV12
```

However I fear this is not possible.

It seems that one cannot define an Azure Automation with predefined Parameter values, or is this to do with the runbook code, so I should add 2 instance of "Set-AzureSqlDatabaseEdition" runbook, and then edit the code of each to point to seperate Database servers etc. All a bit puzzling....

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT

I have checked out linking Azure Scheduler to Azure Automation, and there does seem to be an opinion that it is pretty complex with its abilities at present which I agree with. Link is [How to Link Azure Scheduler to Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/27/scheduling-azure-automation-runbooks-with-azure-scheduler/)

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but I must admit I am having some trouble understanding what you are asking. It sounds like you have 3 schedules for weekday morning, weekday night, and weekend start. And you have 4 runbooks, scale down QAV11, scale up QAV11, scale down QAV12, and scale up QAV12. You should be able to associate each runbook with each schedule as needed, and manage parameters for each association independently. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You mention above that a schedule can only take one job -- that is not the case. You probably meant you can only associate a runbook with a schedule once (one job per runbook per schedule), which is correct. Just want to clarify for anyone else who comes across this post.

For what you are trying to do, I would recommend creating a runbook that starts your other runbooks (inline or as separate jobs, up to you). Put that runbook on a schedule that covers all intervals needed, and have it, within the runbook, check the current time to determine what other runbooks it should start, and what parameters it should pass them.

In addition, we will have a blog post coming out soon on how to (much more easily) link Azure Scheduler jobs to start Azure Automation runbooks (using Azure Automation webhooks). This is another way to do this.

**Update:** Here's the blog post I mention: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/05/scheduling-azure-automation-runbooks-with-azure-scheduler-2/